# Android LinearLayoutManager creates NullPointerException (bug in Android code?)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a `LinearLayoutManager` set to my `RecyclerView`. In my code I invoke:

```
int firstFullyVisibleIndex = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

and get this crash from some (a small percentage of) users:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager$2.getChildStart(RecyclerView.java:7381)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ViewBoundsCheck.findOneViewWithinBoundFlags(ViewBoundsCheck.java:223)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findOneVisibleChild(LinearLayoutManager.java:1941)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition(LinearLayoutManager.java:1874)
...
```

So I looked into the Android source code. In `LinearLayoutManager` I see:

```
public int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() {
    View child = this.findOneVisibleChild(0, this.getChildCount(), true, false);
    return child == null ? -1 : this.getPosition(child);
}

View findOneVisibleChild(int fromIndex, int toIndex, boolean completelyVisible, boolean acceptPartiallyVisible) {
    this.ensureLayoutState();
    int preferredBoundsFlag = false;
    int acceptableBoundsFlag = 0;
    short preferredBoundsFlag;
    if (completelyVisible) {
        preferredBoundsFlag = 24579;
    } else {
        preferredBoundsFlag = 320;
    }

    if (acceptPartiallyVisible) {
        acceptableBoundsFlag = 320;
    }

    return this.mOrientation == 0 ? this.mHorizontalBoundCheck.findOneViewWithinBoundFlags(fromIndex, toIndex, preferredBoundsFlag, acceptableBoundsFlag) : this.mVerticalBoundCheck.findOneViewWithinBoundFlags(fromIndex, toIndex, preferredBoundsFlag, acceptableBoundsFlag);
}
```

The last line `this.mHorizontalBoundCheck.findOneViewWithinBoundFlags()` leads me to `ViewBoundsCheck`:

```
View findOneViewWithinBoundFlags(int fromIndex, int toIndex, int preferredBoundFlags, int acceptableBoundFlags) {
    int start = this.mCallback.getParentStart();
    int end = this.mCallback.getParentEnd();
    int next = toIndex > fromIndex ? 1 : -1;
    View acceptableMatch = null;

    for (int i = fromIndex; i != toIndex; i += next) {
        View child = this.mCallback.getChildAt(i);
        int childStart = this.mCallback.getChildStart(child);
        int childEnd = this.mCallback.getChildEnd(child);
        this.mBoundFlags.setBounds(start, end, childStart, childEnd);
        if (preferredBoundFlags != 0) {
            this.mBoundFlags.resetFlags();
            this.mBoundFlags.addFlags(preferredBoundFlags);
            if (this.mBoundFlags.boundsMatch()) {
                return child;
            }
        }

        if (acceptableBoundFlags != 0) {
            this.mBoundFlags.resetFlags();
            this.mBoundFlags.addFlags(acceptableBoundFlags);
            if (this.mBoundFlags.boundsMatch()) {
                acceptableMatch = child;
            }
        }
    }

    return acceptableMatch;
}
```

Note the first two lines in the for loop. In the crash case, `getChildAt()` returns null and pass it to `getChildStart()`. The callback implementation is in `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`, which says:

```
public View getChildAt(int index) {
    return LayoutManager.this.getChildAt(index);
}

public int getChildStart(View view) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
    return LayoutManager.this.getDecoratedLeft(view) - params.leftMargin;
}
```

As you can see, the `getChildStart()` needs a non-null argument of `view`, otherwise it will create NullPointerException. And the `getChildAt()` simply calls the same name method in `LayoutManager`, which returns nullable:

```
@Nullable
public View getChildAt(int index) {
    return this.mChildHelper != null ? this.mChildHelper.getChildAt(index) : null;
}
```

So my question is:

1. Is it a bug of Android code?

   - 1.1 If yes, what should I do to handle it in my code?
   - 1.2 If no, why, and what should I do to handle it in my code?

---

Address comments:

> Could you please post the code where you're creating the layoutmanager instance.
>
> Is it possible for you to post the whole code? Including how you setup the layout manager, and the way you set the child view inside RecyclerView?

The `LayoutManager` here is a very simple child class of `LinearLayoutManager` with an extra field. The whole code is here:

```
static class MyLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

    MyLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return isScrollEnabled;
    }

    void setScrollEnabled(boolean isScrollEnabled) {
        this.isScrollEnabled = isScrollEnabled;
    }

}
```

Its instance is created and set in constructor of `RecyclerView`, like this:

(Inside of the RecyclerView's constructor:)

```
setLayoutManager(new MyLayoutManager(context));
```

Then the `RecyclerView` adds children through Adapter. The code of the view and Adapter is too long and not likely to contribute to the issue, so I think we can skip them, unless we have reason to believe they do (contribute to the issue), then I will paste the code or the part we are interested in.

I feel confused because all I did is calling a native method: `linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();`, then crash happened (we are still working on how to reproduce it but I suspect it's a race condition giving it only happened on a few users). Maybe some unusual cases trigger it, but shouldn't the method handle it better? In the Android resource code I pasted above, we can see an nullable view is passed to a method which invokes on the view without null checking. I wonder if that's a problem that Google needs to do something? On the other hand, if the code is fine and it's our duty to ensure the unusual cases never happen, then how?

Comment: _"while the getChildStart() needs a non-null argument of view"_ Nothing in the code proves that: it's Java, not Kotlin. Besides, by the time `view.getLayoutParams()` gets invoked `view` might become `null` due to Activity/Fragment being invisible to user, so that the system has killed the view. Doubt it's  a bug. You might consider to null check.

Comment: I doubt if the bug is from the Android codes. Could you please post the code where you're creating the layoutmanager instance.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the whole code? Including how you setup the layout manager, and the way you set the child view inside `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @Onik Thanks for the suggestion. I believe the argument should be non-null because its method is invoked without null checking, so it's possible to throw NullPointerException. I updated my question to point it out. For your suggestion of null check, since the invoking of `view.getLayoutParams()` is living in Android code, I don't see how we can do it...

Comment: @DevMike01 and @ dumbfingers Thanks. I added more information according your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the null value yourself by using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < layoutManager.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (layoutManager.getChildAt(i) == null) {
        return NO_POSITION;
    }
}

int scrollPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug, you can try to catch the exception to avoid crash

```
static class MyLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

    public MyLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
      return isScrollEnabled;
    }

    void setScrollEnabled(boolean isScrollEnabled) {
      this.isScrollEnabled = isScrollEnabled;
    }

    public MyLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public MyLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
        
    //... Your code

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        try {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```